# I'm getting jetified-kotlin-reflect error while getting the release of the app in android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, minify, android-r8

`app:minifyReleaseWithR8` throws an error when it comes here. There is no error when minify is false.

This error.

```
Type kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsResourceLoader is defined multiple times: C:\Users\ErtugrulKoc\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\657211715f0186205ddc0da1f04cb9b6\transformed\jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.5.30.jar:kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class, C:\Users\ErtugrulKoc\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\657211715f0186205ddc0da1f04cb9b6\transformed\jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.5.30.jar:META-INF/versions/9/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class
```

---

```
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\ErtugrulKoc\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\657211715f0186205ddc0da1f04cb9b6\transformed\jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.5.30.jar:kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/serialization/deserialization/builtins/BuiltInsResourceLoader.class

 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: When I try in my Linux machine everything is OK, but in Mac I get this error. Any solution?